# DRY schema definitions in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, functions

What is the recommended way to abstract out common code when writing the database schema?

I've multiple tables that have `created_at` and `updated_at` columns.

```sql
create table if not exists profiles
(
    ...
    created_at timestamptz not null default now(),
    updated_at timestamptz not null default now()
);

...

create index on profiles (created_at);
create index on profiles (updated_at);

create trigger handle_updated_at
    before update
    on profiles
    for each row
execute procedure moddatetime(updated_at);
```

Repeating this code for each table has the following drawbacks

1. pain to write
2. difficult to refactor (say you have to change `created_at` to `created`)
3. the real intent of the code gets buried due to too much boilerplate

Other usecases

- automatically adding an index to all foreign key constraints
- automatically creating mapping tables to represent relation b/w two entities

---

Solutions I'm aware of

1. use an ORM - most ORMs allow you to write abstract classes that don't map to any database table, but can be inherited by child classes that do map to tables.
2. write a function that takes in a table name and alters the table to add the desired columns, triggers and indices

   ```sql
   create or replace function add_created_at(table_name varchar(63))
       returns void
       language plpgsql
       security invoker
   as
   $$
   begin
    execute format('alter table %I add column created_at timestamptz not null;', table_name);
   end;
   $$;
   ```

   I don't particularly like this because I'm being forced to encode the query as a string.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You could search for temporal tables - there is an extension by [Vlad Arkhipov](https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables) might be overkill There's also a PL/pgSQL version [here](https://github.com/nearform/temporal_tables). I don't know what your hacking skills are like, but you might be able to get something from these? It's really a pity that temporal functionality is not first class in PostgreSQL!

Comment: Did you find this helpful at all?

Comment: @Vérace-СлаваУкраїні I did end up creating a bunch of meta functions to alter the tables. Made the code a lot simpler to manage for me. Note that this is for a personal project. I wouldn't do something like this if I expect other people to read my code.

Comment: There is a Postgres extension for bitemporal, it is being actively developed and has already many nice features: https://github.com/scalegenius/pg_bitemporal

Comment: An ORM might be overkill, but using a simple scripting language (Python, Perl, JS etc) to generate the schema definition SQL will grant you the necessary abstractions (and also allows refactoring later).