# How to pass the current row to Generated Column function in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-12, computed-column

Postgres 12+ supports generated columns: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

From the docs, the syntax seems limited - it forces one to explicitly name the columns on which the generated column depends.

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (
    ...,
    height_cm numeric,
    height_in numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS (height_cm / 2.54) STORED
);
```

Is there a way to pass the entire row to the generating function? Something like

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (
    ...,
    height_cm numeric,
    height_in numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS generator_function(current_row) STORED
);
```

Comment: Interesting question (+1). Just as a matter of interest, **why** do you want to do this?

Comment: @Vérace-СлаваУкраїні For DRY code. I've multiple tables for which I need to compute a tsvector and add an index on it for full-text search. My idea was to create a function that alters a given table to add the column and the index, and have individual `x_tsvector()` convertors that take a row from table `x` and produce a tsvector. Sadly, postgres doesn't support fancy metaprogramming. :( https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/302599/dry-schema-definitions-in-postgres

Comment: Does any RDBMS system support fancy metaprogramming?

Comment: None that I know of. It would be lovely if they start doing it though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible.

If it did work, it could only work by first creating the table, then the function, then adding the generated column.

However, doing that:

```
CREATE TABLE people 
(
  id int,
  height_cm numeric
);

create function generator_function(p_row people)
  returns numeric
as
$$
  select p_row.height_cm / 2.54;
$$
language sql
immutable;

alter table people
   add height_in numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS (generator_function(people)) STORED;
```

Results in:

> ERROR: cannot use whole-row variable in column generation expression
>    Detail: This would cause the generated column to depend on its own value.

So, this does not seem to be possible.

Comment: "This would cause the generated column to depend on its own value."
Ah, that makes a lot of sense!